# A part of the proof that $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ is a subgroup of Symmetric Group of G ($S_G$).

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group

So my proof from a textbook reads:

> "$\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ is a subset of $S_G$ and since $id \in \operatorname{Aut}(G)$, we may apply a subgroup test [Let G be a group and H be a nonempty subset of G. If $\forall a,b\in H, ab^{-1}\in H$, then H is a subgroup of G].
>
> Suppose $\alpha, \beta \in \operatorname{Aut}(G)$. Then $\alpha\beta: G\to G$ and $\alpha^{-1}$ are elements of $S_G$, so they are bijective. Therefore it is sufficient to show the operation preserving property."

Why is it enough to show the operation preserving property?

Comment: Was that meant to say $\alpha,\beta\in Aut(G)$ to start with?

Comment: Presumably by "operation preserving property", it means that it suffices to show that $\alpha \beta$ and $\alpha^{-1}$ are homomorphisms. Since you already established that they are bijections, this will imply that they are automorphisms, hence elements of $Aut(G)$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes, you're correct.

Comment: @Bungo Yeah, that they're homomorphisms. But what about the other conditions for being a subgroup: closed under multiplication (is that the homomorphism property in this case?)

Comment: Showing that $\alpha \beta$ is a homomorphism (and also a bijection) implies that $\alpha \beta$ is an automorphism, hence $Aut(G)$ is closed under composition (which is the group operation here). Similarly for inverses.

Comment: Yeah, ok, I think I understand now. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

It means that all one needs to do is show that $\alpha\beta$ and $\alpha^{-1}$ are homomorphisms, since it is already the case that they are bijective on $G$.

It also suffices to prove that $\alpha\beta^{-1}$ is a homomorpism, by the one-step subgroup test.